# How to getElementByID in a specific DIV block (JS or JQUery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I just wanted a fast/easy/simple way to check for existing ID on a specific element (div in this case)..

Can't seem to find code sample for this..im using jquery but i dont think i need to do jquery on this one, just basic getElement.. but i need to isolate the search inside a div block.. because the id does exist in other elements on the page but i need to know if it exist in a specific area/div.

so instead of just

```
document.getElementById(target_id);
```

i need something like:

```
divName.getElementById(target_id);
```

or

```
$("document.divName").getElementById(target_id);
```

or

```
$(".divName").document.getElementById(target_id);
```

Can't seem to find something that works.

Comment: You should not have two elements with the same id on one page; perhaps you would like to rethink your plans? :)

Comment: `var mySubDiv = parentDiv.querySelector("#subDivId")`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IDs are supposed to be **unique** and no two elements in page should have same id. You may search some element with some class in div with specific ID.

```
$('#divId .someClass')
```

or using [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('#divId').find('.someClass')
```

or using [**context**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`

```
$('.someClass', $('#divId'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code samples. i get it. and yes I did not intend to have 2 same IDs in one page.. the system im designing may use the id in specific div areas, hence i need to check w/c div has it in order to process the rest of my routine.. i could use different attribute names on each div areas but i like to keep it standard,using just "id" instead of "id_div1" and "id_div2" etc :)

thanks for the reminder though :)

Answer (score 13):

```
    var mySubDiv = myParentDiv.querySelector("#mySubDivId")
```

is equivalent to

```
    var mySubDiv = document.querySelector("#myParentDivId #mySubDivId"); 
    // don't forget the space :  #myParentDiv#mySubDivId won't work
```

where `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are [very useful functions](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), enough for me to avoid using `jQuery`  : [they accept any `css selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

in real life, using the same Id for different `DOM elements` often happens.

Comment: very usefull trick! thank


    `var x = document.querySelector("#parent").querySelector("#child");`

Comment: I prefer this one as it is the vanilla JS solution (!jQuery)

Answer (score 2):

`id`'s should be unique, you can check for element using:

```
$(".your_parent_div").find("div#some_unique_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it for the getElementsByTagName or ClassName, but ID is unique over document. so doesn't need to do that. better to use a special ID.
and in every id define as a element in javascript and you can just write id's name and use it, like this :
ID.style.color = red;

Answer (score -3):

According to my understanding on your question, You have used two id's with same name when u execute, It takes only first ID so you are asking to take id from the specific div, well that is bad type of coding to use two id for same name instead go for class if want to use same name.
solution for your question is -this ->

```
    var someDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("divName");
    var someId = someDiv[0].getElementById("target_id");
```

Comment: This will throw an exception. `getElementByClassName` doesn't exist, it is `getElemenstByClassName` (plural!). If you fix that it will throw another exception. `getElementById` is a method on the `document` object and **only** the `document`object. It own't appear on a div element.